# Azure aks could not access to EXTERNAL-IP

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I just create aks And create the sample service.

```
kubectl get service azure-vote-front --watch

NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE  
azure-vote-front   LoadBalancer   10.0.1.71    13.71.XXX.XXX   80:31619/TCP   1h
```

I want to acccsss to 13.71.xxx.xxx:31619 but it is waiting not to return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to access the address `13.71.xxx.xxx` through the browser without the port 31619.

Comment: I get the message through 13.71.xxx.xxx

502 Bad Gateway  
nginx/1.13.7

Comment: Does your application work well? use the command `kubectl get service` to get all the service state.

Comment: I recreate resouce . it woks fine. Thank you!!

Comment: But when I use 
 kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=gcr.io/hello-minikube-zero-install/hello-node
 kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080


It does not work well

Comment: You can follow steps [Creating a service for an application running in five pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/#creating-a-service-for-an-application-running-in-five-pods).

Comment: You also should pay attention to the application if it works well. Then the steps will work to you.

Comment: @CharlesXu could you elaborate what the purpose of port 31619 is? It's a NodePort, correct? I'm on AKS as well and i'm struggling to understand what the purpose of that port 3xxxx is when the regular port of the service is used to connect externally.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is setup correctly, navigating to `http://www.13.71.xxx.xxx` should take you straight to the application.

What you can do to ensure that the application is functioning properly is to investigate the image and the pod.

For the image you can run it locally using Docker. `docker run azure-vote-front image=nameOfImage"`. If that works then you have established that the image is functioning offline which is a good first step.

Next step is to debug your pod. You can use the command `kubectl describe pod azure-vot-front-generated-id-number` to get the state of the deployment. If you can't find any errors here either then I'd recommend checking the logs. `kubectl logs -f azure-vote-froned-generated-id-number` will give you the logs of the application. My guess is that by this step you will have found the error and have been able to remedy it.

The part of your output under `PORT(S)` shows the mapping of ports inside your clusted. Any request on port 80 on the external-ip will be filtered to port 31619 inside the cluster. Kubernetes has ensured that the request gets filtered back to port 80 for your application when the request reaches your application. As long as you are exposing the port in your Dockerfile it should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

where is your image stored?

when you configured the K8S yaml file you give it the image location, you need to make sure you have that the service has the credentials for it.

For example, if you are storing it at [Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?WT.mc_id=devto-blog-adpolak) you will need to config the authentication between them to give AKS access to your image [Authentication between ACR and AKS cluster for pulling images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?WT.mc_id=stackoverflow-online-adpolak)

To check yourself run `kubectl get pods`, if you see under status - 'ImagePullBackOff' it means that the action of pulling the image failed.
To dig deeper - run `kubectl describe pod <your pod name>` - Under `EVENTS` - you will find the error message.